# What are the common patterns in web programming?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have been trying to write my first big web app (more than one cgi file) and as I kept moving forward with the rough prototype, paralelly trying to predict more tasks, this is the todo that got accumulated (In no particular order).

```
* Validations and input sanitizations
* Object versioning (to avoid edit conflicts. I dont want hard locks)
* Exception handling
* memcache
* xss and injection protections
    * javascript
    * html
* ACLs
* phonetics in search, match and find duplicates (for form validation)
* Ajaxify!!!
```

(I have snipped off the project specific items.)

I know that each todo will be quite tied up to its project and technologies used. What I am wondering though, is if there is a pattern in your todo items as well as the sequence in which you experienced guys have come across them.

Comment: Thx a lot for the responses, I have zeroed in on Google appengine. That takes a lot of load off me like email, memcache, etc. Good Model support too. I aint *that* happy with Django0.9 templating provided. I've selected cubictemp for now, and have tasted loads of others.

I guess I can manage to fill up the remaing stuff in the list.

Now, I have the frameworks(sort of). I'm still wondering about the sequence you guys end up following. I know the top level dance: mockup, design, code, test, maintain repeat. I want to know the sequence of tasks from the above list & friends.

Comment: What I mean is, The framework provides features for you. But you will have to use it. Right? I am guessing the order in which you learn and use these things starts blurring as you get experience. May be you experienced guys look at API and you already have a picture of what goes where?

Answer (score 4):

If this is actually a big web app that will be deployed for general consumption, then I'd add on Rate Limiting.

Comment: Yeah! that seems to be already either being discussed or in implementation in GAE. SO I think its the cherry on icecream.

Answer (score 3):

The [Model-View-Controller (MVC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design pattern: decouples users inputs and the presentation layer from your application data.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all of your list is "Framework".

Almost none of that is functionality a user actually sees.

My to do list never looks like that.  Never.

Consequently, I have this advice.

STOP.

Do this instead.

1. Find a framework that does this.
2. Focus on the the actual users and their actual use cases.

Now your todo list will have actual use cases that an actual user will actually care about.  That's what should be on your todo list.  Not framework technology.  Use cases.

Comment: I have a different todo list for the use cases .. The list is not something I am going to write. The list is just a set of items I am going to "take care" one by one. 

What I am really interested in, is the sequence of things people take care (on the road from rough prototype to shiny professional app)

But of course.. You did not know about my other todo list. My bad. Thanks a lot for pointing it out anyway. I bet a lot of newbies will find it helpfull.

Comment: @lankerisms:  A to-do list that consists entirely of problems already solved by frameworks is not a list of things to **do**.  It's a list of features.  Just download a framework that has those features.  Stop focusing on framework features.

Answer (score 1):

model view controller of course. start with some framework first. in php kohana is good , for python django is good, ruby on rail and so on...